# What is the error "cannot create a file that's already there"

Tags: batch-file

I'm in the middle of writing a batch file with these lines in it:
First I create 2 directories:

```
MD "C:\PROGRAMFILES\MALWAREBYTES\ANTIMALWARE"
MD "E:\UTILITIES\ANTI\MALWARE\MALWAREBYTES\ANTIMALWARE"
```

My usage of `mklink`:

```
Mklink /D "C:\ProgramFiles\Anti-Malware" "E:\Utilities\Anti\Malware\Malwarebytes\AntiMalware"
```

Now when I run the batch file I get

> Cannot create a file that's already there

- What file is it talking about?
- What do I need to do to make this work?
- Do I need to make both directories?
- Could you rewrite to make it work?

Comment: seems like you repeating this line `"E:\Utilities\Anti\Malware\Malwarebytes\AntiMalware"` once with CAPS and one more time without .

Comment: What part of "file already exists" is unclear?

Comment: `md` makes all directories specified. So `MD "E:\UTILITIES\ANTI\MALWARE\MALWAREBYTES\ANTIMALWARE"` makes both `MALWAREBYTES` and `ANTIMALWARE`. But NOTE there is a typing error in your `mklink` command. You place a `\ ` between `Anti` and `Malware`.

Comment: Syntax is `mklink /d link target`. The *target* folder needs to exist so a *link* can be created by `mklink`. If you create a folder at the same path and name of where you want the *link* created, you will get an error. Only make the *target* directory as `mklink` will make the *link*.